# duplicity: No signature chains found

Tags: duplicity, google-drive

Trying to use duplicity to list files in a backup that is in google drive. I get the error as in the title.

- I can see the folder and contents if I go to drive.google.com in the browser.
- I created a service account and downloaded the json file as defined [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access)
- The url I use is `gdrive://${GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL}/${FOLDER_NAME}?myDriveFolderID=root`
- GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL is the same as client_email in the json fle
- FOLDER_NAME is the textual name I see in the web browser
- The drive is for a company account and usually I access it by logging in normally, but with my work email

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1813097/duplicity-no-signature-chains-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Need to share the drive with the service account
- Neet to not user FOLDER_NAME and instead use its ID in myDriveFolderID